# Ordering a list of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list of integers which I am trying to order in the following way:

- remove all zeros from the list
- sort in increasing order of absolute value
- put positive values before negative values

I.e. the list `n={0,1,-3,3,-3,0,12,10,0}` should go to `{1,3,-3,-3,10,12}`.

I'm very new to Mathematica and can't figure this out although it's probably simple.

Things I tried:

- define a function `simplifyList[n_]:=Sort[n, Less] /. {Longest[0 ...], x___} :> {x}`. This only works when there are no negative values, otherwise zeros remain.
- `Sort[DeleteCases[n, 0], Abs[#1] < Abs[#2] &]`. This returns `{1, -3, 3, -3, 10, 12}` with the list `n` above, i.e. the negative/positive numbers with same absolute value are not sorted.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Speed is quite important here, as the simplifying-list function will be used 1000s of times, so the more efficient the better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = ReverseSortBy[Minus @* Abs] @* DeleteCases[0] 

f @ n
```

> {1, 3, -3, -3, 10, 12}

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
In[21]:= n = (Sort[{0, 1, -3, 3, -3, 0, 12, 10, 0} /. 
x_ /; x == 0 -> Nothing, Abs[#1] < Abs[#2] &])
```

(*  Out[21]= {1, -3, 3, -3, 10, 12}   *)

Then

```
     In[23]:= Sort[n, If[Abs[#1] == Abs[#2], #1 > #2] &]

(*   Out[23]= {1, 3, -3, -3, 10, 12}   *)
```

Have fun!